# How can I create a onEnterFrame animation in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to create interactivity inside an iPad app.

I would like to spin an image gallery, I would use a pan or swipe move to set the speed and let it decrease with the time.

Since I come from Actionscript world I would use onEnterFrame handler to do so, but I dont know how can I do that in Objective-C

**EDIT:
The movement I want to add is similar to a coverflow menu.**

**My question is:**
How can I efficiently execute code inside a method which is executed on every frame ( or similar to onEnterframe ) ?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of calculations is it that you have to do for very frame? If it's only UI related then you should probably just try to find a suitable "to value" and let the OS do the interpolation for you.

Comment: Executing code for every frame is probably never very "efficient".

Comment: I want to set a speed according to the size of the swipe and then reduce the speed as soon as I remove my finger from the screen, like letting it die slowly....

Comment: Have you looked at just using a UIScrollView? It will do the paning and decelerate when you lift your finger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about frames I'm assuming that you want to do UI code for very frame.

### Custom drawing every "frame"

You *could* execute code for every frame by implementing a custom view and use a NSTimer that fires 60 times a second and calls `[self
setNeedsDisplay];`. Now your custom views `drawRect:` method will be called for every frame.

Now you have code that executes every frame. I would say that this probably isn't the most efficient way of doing things, especially if you don't change the view between every frame.

### Callbacks from the gesture recognizer

The gesture recognizer gives you callbacks whenever the user swipes or pans. If you only want to move your views in response to the this then putting your code in these methods will work fine.

Using this approach you will only execute your code when there are changes to respond to.

### Cover flow using Core Animation

If it is something similar to cover flow that you are trying to do then you could most likely do it using Core Animation. It is a bit to complicated to describe exactly how to do it here and besides I don't know the details of how you want it to look but there are many good resources on the web that describe how you can create something like Cover flow.

One resource is the [Core Animation screencasts by Bill Dudney](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdcora/creating-a-compelling-user-interface-with-core-animation) where he creates a Cover flow UI with Core Aniation. It *is*  a few years old and is aimed towards the Mac but most of it still applies to iOS.

Comment: I'll probably go for the first solution if I don't find anything else. Thanks @David.

Comment: @xavi The first solution probably isn't the best one. It's close to fighting the framework. I would advise you to rethink _how_ you want to approach this to find a way that better suits the platform. I'm not telling you to change how the solution would look to the user, just to look at thing like Core Animation or custom UIScollViews where the OS can do most of the heavy calculations for you

Comment: @XaviColomer I've updated my answer with a link to a screencast that creates a Cover flow using Core Animation. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is to implement it in [viewWillAppear method of the UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a)

Comment: Thanks @Oleg but as far as I understand this method only executes once. I need a continuous calculations / execution. Am I right?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called once, this method is called every time the view appears, for example when returninng from another screen.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't explain enough. It's a custom image scroller, the view is always there. I'm scrolling images via swipe / pan gesture, I want the set a speed that will be decreasing as soon as I remove the finger from the screen.

Comment: How are you moving images? What do you use for it?

Comment: I'm swiping my finger over the view to slide the images to a direction. Left or Right. I want it to be smoothly animated

Comment: :) Well you don't provide enough info: are the pictures on a UIScrollView, is it a cover flow view, or how is the animation now working? In different cases, depending on the mechanism you use for browsing the pictures the solution might be different. Swiping is just a gesture, which allows you to handle it, the swipe gesture does not move the picture, it just allows you to make code, so you move the picture in any manner you want.